# bsxfun rows subtraction in loop

Tags: matlab, row, subtraction, bsxfun

I have a text file `D` with 98 rows and 2 columns. looks like this:

> 10             0.261344
>    11     0.456167
>    12     0.668595
>    2      0.481754
>    ... etc

I have another excel file `M` with 17 rows and 2 col.
I want to subtract all rows values from the 1st row, then from 2, etc.so i get something like this:

> 10-11    -0.194823
>   10-12   -0.407251
>    ... etc

in other words difference between 1st row and all rest, 2nd row and all rest ..excluding those rows of which 1st column has same values as in 2nd M excel file 1st column. which makes in total difference compare to 81 rows.

i have been trying to use this:

```
M = xlsread('...');    

FSumID=fopen(D);
 MatrixSub = loadD);
 m = textscan(FSumID,'%d %f');
horzcat(m{:}) 

NewData = M(:,1)
D_size=size(D);

for i=1:D_size

 if (ptvBodyDist(:,1)~=NewData(i))
%for calculating 
 DVec = bsxfun(@minus, ((m{i,2})), (m{i,2}));
```

%when i check this it gives only one loop all zeros(98,1)while i need (((98-17)^2,1). I need to change,last part of expression to get what i want but I'm stuck with bsxfun. i dont know how to make correct expression to subtract all rows.

I'm newbie in Matlab any help would be much appreciated. also if you could suggest some manuals or tutorials,apart from mathworks help. Many thanks.

Comment: Back up for a minute and make sure the first part of this code is working the way you intend.  The typos make it difficult to tell, but for example the result of `horzcat(m{:})` isn't saved to any variable at all.  Next, write a small test case that starts with hand-entered matrices so that people here have something to work with to test/demonstrate solutions to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `D` be `n` by `2` matrix (data from text file).
Let `M` by `m` by `2` matrix (data from excel file).

The first stage is to find the relevant `n-m` rows of `D`: rows that their first value does not appear in `M`, using [`setdiff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html).

```
[~, idx] = setdiff( D( :, 1 ), M( :, 1 ), 'stable' );
```

Now we can compute the all-vs-all diff using `bsxfun`

```
d = bsxfun( @minus, permute( D( idx, : ), [1 3 2] ), ...
                    permute( D( idx, : ), [3 1 2] ) );
```

Now `d` is |`idx`|x|`idx`|x`2` array where

```
d( ii, jj, : ) = D( idx(ii), :) - D( idx(jj), : )
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your reply. I have been trying to implement this method. I have a few questions. in bsxfun expression when you put dots after first permute what do you mena by that? i just omitted it. Also the last expression gives me error:"Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch." when I put ii and jj in the loop: for ii,jj=1:d_size. thats how i thought of defining ii and jj. otherwise i get error:"Undefined function or variable 'ii'" if i dont mention loop. I know it might sound trivial question but i would appreciate explanation a lot. thank you!

Comment: @mil Regarding the three dots: in matlab if you have an expression that is longer than a single line, you can cut it to several lines and put '...' at the end of each (partial) line. see [matlab doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/continue-long-statements-on-multiple-lines.html).

Comment: @mil Regarding the last expression `d( ii, jj, : ) = D( idx(ii), :) - D( idx(jj), : )` I did **not** mean it as a Matlab command. I meant it as a general statement, for each `ii` and `jj` (in range) the diff `D( idx(ii), :) - D( idx(jj), : )` is stored in `d(ii,jj,:)`.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. regarding D( idx(ii), :) - D( idx(jj), : ) is stored in d(ii,jj,:).. I need the outcome result to be d(6561,2).which comes from rows = 81*81,col =2 .Does d( ii, jj, : )result give that? Im still trying to understand d( ii, jj, : ) = D( idx(ii), :) - D( idx(jj), : ).Could you explain that a bit more please? Many thanks!

Comment: @mil try out the code with small example and check the contents of the resulting arrays. Furthermore, you can use [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) for re-arranging the resulting array to the desired dimensions.

Comment: Thank you Shai! I'm working on it now-your advice helped a lot!

Comment: Hello! In the previous answer it subtracts 1st columns as well and presents them in D (:,:,1) while i need to keep them and in fact i need them to be showed as 10-11,10-12,10-2(i.e. which col was subtracted from which)..etc ..could you give a help on how it would be possible to do that? Thanks in advance!